# How do I request from an API and parse the JSON response in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

**api endpoint: https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/achievements/daily**

**I am new to api interfacing and web apps in general**

According to Node's API docs, HTTPS.get returns a ClientRequest object.

My code is the following:

```
var dailiesURL = 'https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/achievements/daily';
var dailies = https.get(dailiesURL, parseResponse);

function parseResponse(response) {
    var body = '';

    response.on('data', function(chunk) {
        body += chunk;
    });
    response.on('end', function() {
       dailyResponse =  JSON.parse(body);
       console.log(dailyResponse); 
    });
    response.on('error', function(e) {
        console.log("Got an error: ", e);
    });
}

console.log(dailies);
```

The documentation says that the callback function in https.get should make sure to store off the json data as get returns a ClientRequest object. I'm struggling to figure out exactly how one saves off the parsed json.

Should I be using something other than https.get/request?

Comment: @Phil The question you linked to answered the question with jQuery, not with Node.js. I understand there is a lot of academic material in the question you linked, but it does not give me an answer to my question.

Comment: You can return a `Promise`